# How can I remove duplicate values across years from a panel dataset if I'm applying a condition to a certain year?

Tags: r, filtering, subset, tidyr, panel-data

I have panel dataset that looks likes this -

```
CompanyName  Industry  Year   Sales   Assets...
A             Gas      2015   150     900
A             Gas      2016   100     1,000
A             Gas      2017   107     1,500
B             Gas      2015   90      900
B             Gas      2016   100     1,000
B             Gas      2017   99      1,500
```

I wanted to create a subset that is conditional on - if Sales are greater than 100 in the year 2017 then I want to remove the corresponding company from my panel across years.

I have tried to create a filter condition and created a newdata set however, I am unable to remove the companies across years.

subset(data, data$Year == 2017 & data$Sales > 100)

I am trying to find a way to remove the companies that i get from the above condition across years to created a balanced panel

Answer (score 0):

One option would be

```
subset(data, !CompanyName %in% unique(CompanyName[Sales[Year == 2017] > 100]))
```

Or it can be written as

```
subset(data, !CompanyName %in% unique(CompanyName[Year == 2017 & Sales > 100]))
```